# Access and set iphone default alarm

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I want to access iphone default alarm and set the alarm according to the date submitted by user.I also want user to change the sound of alarm.
Is it possible to do that and if it's possible how can I do that?
Is that any code available for that?
Please help me to bring me out of this.

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to *read* the iOS default alarm using this code, but this is an undocumented method and would not be allowed in the App Store.

Below is Alan Yip's post, copied from http://blog.alanyip.me/read-alarms-in-ios/

> There is a private framework ([MobileTimer.framework](https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS6-Private-Frameworks/tree/master/MobileTimer.framework)) originally
>   provided for iOS stock app, Clock to manipulate clocks and system
>   alarms.
>
> Obviously, we will only use two classes when dealing with alarms,
>   [AlarmManager](https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS6-Private-Frameworks/blob/master/MobileTimer.framework/AlarmManager.h) and [Alarm](https://github.com/caughtinflux/iOS6-Private-Frameworks/blob/master/MobileTimer.framework/Alarm.h). First, we have to get the singleton
>   instance of **AlarmManager**.
>
> ```
> AlarmManager *manager = [AlarmManager sharedManager];
> ```
>
> Before accessing the alarms, it is required to load alarms first.
>
> ```
> [manager loadAlarms];
> ```
>
> Then, you can access the array containing all available alarms
>   (**Alarm**) in Clock app.
>
> ```
> NSArray *alarms = [manager alarms];
> ```
>
> However, there is a problem in the framework when loading the alarms.
>   For example, the  code is running in SpringBoard, while at the same
>   time the alarms are being modified in stock Clock app. Even if you
>   load alarms in SpringBoard again, the alarm data returned are still
>   outdated. To fix this, hook a class method in **AlarmManager** to
>   force synchronizing the preference values before the original method
>   read from the preference.
>
> ```
> %hook AlarmManager
>
> + (id)copyReadAlarmsFromPreferences {
>   CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(CFSTR("com.apple.mobiletimer"));
>   return %orig;
> }
>
> %end
> ```
>
> Lastly, calling `refreshActiveState` before `isActive` may be a way to
>   read whether the alarm is enabled or not.

Comment: Rather than copy a blog post, come up with your *own summary*. See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) in the help centre.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking to **access iphone default alarm**. there is no way to do that. In any case if you find a way to do this..you definitely wouldn't get allowed into the App Store.

If you're looking to make an alarm-clock application...you have to use [Scheduling Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1)