# Read the alarm entries for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

Is there a way to read what times are set for the native alarm in iOS? I want to read them and give a notification if it doesn't match a certain criteria.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access iPhone alarm from app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860001/access-iphone-alarm-from-app)